# How can I exclude folders when updating drupal using drush?

Tags: drush, updating

How can I use `drush pm_update` and exclude some folders? For example, I don't want to update Sites and Profiles folders.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to update Drupal core without updating contrib, use `drush pm-update drupal`.  Always upgrade a copy of your site and test it before modifying your production site.

If you want to avoid updating just a specific contrib project, use `drush pm-update --lock=skipthis`.  The lock is persistent until removed with --unlock.

Comment: But can I use lock to exclude some directories? For example:
drush pm-update --lock=sites,profiles
Or this is only working for modules?

Comment: The --lock feature only works at the project level. `drush pm-update drupal` will only update Drupal, it will not touch contrib modules or profiles. If you want to be extra careful, always explicitly name the project you want to update on the commandline (e.g. `drush pm-update views`).